# Why are hanging icicles on my home yellow?

Tags: roof, shingles

The icicles hanging on the front of my house are yellow on the tips. I also noticed a yellow line in the snow beneath the icicles. We moved into this home recently and I know they had the roof replaced due to hail damage. Any idea what would cause the yellow? Is this glue from the overhanging shingles?

[image][image]

Comment: Pollen on the roof before the snow?

Comment: Someone peeing on your roof?   Don't drink the yellow icicles!

Comment: could also be dust, there's a lot of it outside sometimes...

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the water is absorbing stain from the new shingles.

This will change over time as the new shingles weather.